# prevent nextjs from rendering undefiend routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, routes, render

I have a nextjs application and I have defined the route /vendor or /admin but the thing is I have not defined /admin/something but nextjs automatically renders admin page for
/admin/something even if i have not define such a route
I just wanted to return a not found page for these cases
I would really appreciate your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**

> I just wanted to return a not found page

**Solution :**

**If you  are using `app router` then** :

1. You need to create a file called `not-found.js` *(don't keep any other name its according to NextJS file conventions)* at the root of your project.
2. It will handle all invalid URL's throughout the project.

Here's a small example code :

`not-found.js` at location(folder structure) `projectName\src\app\not-found.js` :

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function NotFound() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Not Found Page</h2>
            <p>Page doesn't exists</p>
            <Link href="/">Go to Home</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

**If you are using `Pages Router`** :

1. You need to create a file with name `404.js` *(don't keep any other
   name its according to NextJS file conventions)* at root of `pages`
   folder `pages/404.js`.

> ```
> import Link from "next/link";
>
> export default function NotFound() {
>     return <div>
>         <h2>Not Found Page</h2>
>         <p>Page doesn't exists</p>
>         <Link href="/">Go to Home</Link>
>     </div>
> }
> ```

**Output :**

3. Go to any invalid urls, & this page will be visible.

***Please Read :***

4. not-found.js *(If using app router)* : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found
5. 404 Page *(if using pages router)* : https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-error#404-page

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment.***